# CGBitmapContextGetData in Monotouch

Tags: image-processing, xamarin.ios

hello i am trying to manipulate bitmap data in monotouch.

what is the equivalent of  **CGBitmapContextGetData**  in monotouch.

and are there any other methods to change the image bitmap data?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the equivalent of CGBitmapContextGetData in monotouch.

The [`CGBitmapContextGetData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextGetData) function is mapped to the [`CGBitmapContext.Data`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aMonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGBitmapContext.Data) property in MonoTouch.

> and are there any other methods to change the image bitmap data?

*Nearly* all CoreGraphics functions are mapped to C# methods/properties (if not, fill a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com)). Use the previous links to see what's available or (as a last resort) you can use the pointer to modify the data itself.